# Is there a way to detect fatal JS error caused by other script

Tags: javascript

Is there a way **from the javascript code** to detect that another script (which is out of your control) has caused a fatal error on the page?
The situation is this. The user installs your script on their site. If something on their site caused fatal error your script also won't work. Is there a way to detect this and prevent it or at least alert the user that something is causing fatal error?

Comment: You mean like a parser error?

Comment: check if the class/function names defined in the script are defined. If undefined we can assume its not loaded or error occured.

Comment: Running `window.onerror = function(message, file, line, column, errorObj) { ... }` as your first script might help, although `onerror` fires for lots of things, including `throw`s and parse errors.

Comment: @Brad, yes, typically a parse error from another script. Or object not defined etc. - any fatal error